# My Always Free Oracle Autonomous DB login is asking for 2 factor authentication and a bypass code, how do I obtain the bypass code

Tags: clouddb

My Always Free Oracle cloud Autonomous DB login is asking for 2 factor authentication and a bypass code, how do I obtain the bypass code. The account was paused due to inactivity, I am trying to restart, but after login password, it is asking for a bypass code.

Login to Oracle cloud Autonomous DB

Comment: Did you check: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/usids/generate-bypass-code.html It says: *Use the Security tab in Oracle Identity Cloud Service My Profile console to generate bypass codes for your account.*